# Laravel IDE autocomplete on models

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete

I have a small question, when you retrieve objects from a database , is it possible to check which properties are on that object ? I've generated phpDocs with Laravel ide helper (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) but I don't see any properties..

This is my code :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * App\Planning
 *
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property \Carbon\Carbon $created_at
 * @property \Carbon\Carbon $updated_at
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\App\Planning whereCreatedAt($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\App\Planning whereId($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\App\Planning whereName($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\App\Planning whereUpdatedAt($value)
 */
class Planning extends Model
{


    function test()
    {
        $planningItems = App\Planning::all();

        foreach ($planningItems as $item) {
             echo $item->?;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello Vladyslav , yes I need the $name , I can access it with $item->name but isn't there a way for autocompleting it , so that the IDE shows which properties there are (imagine 15 properties) ? I am using Netbeans. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you get autocomplete when you instantiate the model, and use it straight away?

```
$planning = new App\Planning();
$planning->??
```

That works for me. If it also works for you, but the example in the OP does not, then it could be down to needing to hint the method, something like this:

```
@method static \App\Planning[] all()
```

Or :

```
function test()
{
    /** @var App\Planning[] $planningItems */
    $planningItems = App\Planning::all();

    foreach ($planningItems as $item) {
         echo $item->?;
    }
}
```

If those don't work, then it's probably time to raise an issue with the makers of the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to resurrect this question with what I think is finally a potential solution to this problem. After researching around, it requires PHP 8 and most likely the latest eloquent version. But this package seems to do exactly what you want.

https://github.com/lepikhinb/laravel-fluent

> With laravel-fluent, you can define Model attributes as you would do with any other class. The values will be transformed to the corresponding types depending on the native types of the properties.

```
Before: 
<?php
/**
 * @property Collection $features
 * @property float $price
 * @property int $available
 */
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'features' => 'collection',
        'price' => 'float',
        'available' => 'integer',
    ];
}

After:
<?php

class Product extends Model
{
    use Fluent;

    public Collection $features;
    public float $price;
    public int $available;
}
```

This won't help you if you're stuck on old versions or whatever, since this requires all those nice new toys we have in modern PHP 8. But I think for people who maintain projects these days, that might not be such a problem!